# $*$-homomorphism induced by a c.p.c order zero map

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

[image]

The $*$-homomorphism $\Phi:C_0((0,1])\otimes A\rightarrow B$  is defined in (3).

If $f$ is any nonzero element in $C_0((0,1])$, how to define $\Phi(f\otimes a)$? where $a\in A$

Comment: Is this a tensor product of $C^*$-algebras?

Comment: What are the title and author(s) of the paper?

Comment: This is  the link .https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123620302330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the formula, you can get an explicit calculation of $\Phi(p\otimes a)$ whenever $p$ is a polynomial with $p(0)=0$ and $a\in A$.  Since such polynomials are dense in $C_0((0,1])$, we can approximate $\Phi(f\otimes a)$ for any $f\in C_0((0,1])$.

Let $p$ be such a polynomial, with $p(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kx^k$, and assume $a\in A$ is positive (since positive elements span $A$, we can find $\Phi(p\otimes a)$ for arbitrary $A$ by linearity).  Then we have
$$\Phi(p\otimes a)=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k\Phi(x^k\otimes a)=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k\left(\Phi(x\otimes a^{1/k})\right)^k =\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k\phi(a^{1/k})^k.$$

If $A$ is unital and $f\in C_0((0,1])$, choose a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)$ in $C_0((0,1])$ converging to $f$.  Since $1^{1/k}=1$ for all $k$, the above formula implies that
$$\Phi(f\otimes 1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Phi(p_n\otimes1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n(\phi(1))=f(\phi(1)).$$

Comment: In the 7th page of the paper. The authors get the following result :$\Phi(f\otimes 1)=f(\phi(1))$. I am a little confused.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: The domain of $\pi_{\omega}$ in that paper should be $\prod A_i$, but $f(\phi(1))\in \Bbb C$.

Comment: No.  $1$ is the unit of $A$, everything here lies in $B$.

Comment: I mean the domain of $\pi_{\omega}$. Is $f(\phi(1))$ a complex number?

Comment: I am puzzled about the range of $f$. Is its range $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Since $f\in C_0((0,1])$, by definition its range lies in $\mathbb C$.  However, when we consider the continuous functional calculus, the element $f(\phi(1))$ lies in the same algebra as $\phi(1)$.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much

Comment: I need to learn more from you. May I know your research  topic? Would you mind recommending some papers or reference books? THANKS!